# How to change the root directory locations in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Can you please tell me how should I change the default root directory  in SQL 2005 Std. Edition.

Currently its configured to:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL
and I want to change the drive letter here.

I'm unsure how and where to configure this.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Would you like to move the data files, the entire program files, the backup location, the log location?

Comment: This is a [DBA issue](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @TomV I want to physically move the root directory to another drive, during installation SQL 2005 doesn't give an option to change the path so i want to know if there is any other way to do that.

Comment: So you don't want to change the database location, but the entire install folder? If so, make sure that's clear from the question.

Comment: My question was edited by @Tanner but now its back to the original one, could you please help me out?

Comment: I would remove the "(used for db storage)" to avoid confusion with the database location.

Comment: As @TomV says, the question is unclear and that statement "(used for db storage)" is the reason I edited the question in the way I did as I assumed that's what you were trying to do. "Default installation directory" is what you want to refer to.

Comment: Also, you may want to edit your title again so it's applicable to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the root directory once it's installed. Just copying over the install directory and changing registry keys is a hacky solution that will probably lead to all kinds of problems.

Your safest option is probably to back up all your databases and then uninstall and reinstall SQL server.

During the setup at the "instance configuration" step you can select the root directory.

See [this screenshot](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/SQLServer/DBA_tips/Installation/resources/InstallSQLServer2008R2/install_sql_server_2008_r2_screen_12-1-small.png)